# Webshops implemented in JadaSite

Tags: java, webshop

I made a fast google search about this topic but I can't find any relevant result. So, does anyone knows at least one example of a realworld webpage that uses JadaSite as its webshop implementation? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This online store released using jada:
http://www.silver-river.com.au/